# VSTO add "empty" DocumentProperty

Tags: c#, vsto

I am currently working on a VSTO project for my company and to help a customer with some strange workaround i need to save two spaces (`"  "`) as value of a DocumentProperty.
Here is a code snippet how i use it until now:

```cs
public void SavePropertiesToDocument(IEnumerable<ContentControl> contentControls)
{
    DocumentProperties documentProperties = Document.CustomDocumentProperties;

    var propertiesToPersist = GetPropertiesFromInMemoryManager()

    foreach (var property in propertiesToPersist)
    {
        documentProperties.Add(property.Name, false, MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, property.ValueToPersist);
    }
}
```

This works fine so far. 
But now i need to save an "empty" property where the `property.ValueToPersist` is `"  "` (exactly two spaces). 
I attached the debugger inside the foreach loop and the name/value of the property i want to save are correct at this point, but when i look into the markup of the document afterwards the property is there but without a value:

```xml
<property fmtid="{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}" pid="17" name="propertyName">
    <vt:lpwstr/>
</property>
```

And of course if i reopen the document and read those properties the said property has no value.
Is there any way to preserve whitespaces when adding the properties? Or is there any other way around this?
As i have no control over what the `.Add` really does.

Any help would be much appreciated!

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering of course you can not just save whitespaces as XML values they get removed. Our solution was to just wrap them in `{  }` when saving it and removing them when reading them into our InMemory Property Manager.